# c# Linq, how return query with ENUM

Tags: linq, enums, c3.js

So from Front-end I get a string `"test1,test2,test3"` or `"test1,test2"` etc. (I can change this on number, it is not a problem);

In back-end I have this:

```
class Car 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }
}
    
public enum Color
{
    Red = 1,
    Blue = 2,
    Pink = 3,
    Orange = 4,
}

public async Task<Car> GetAllCars(string searchString)
{
    switch (searchString)
    {
        case "How create here query guestion whcih inlude ENUMS":
            query = query.Where( inlude x=> a.Color == x.Contains(x.Color))
        break;

        default:
            query = query.Where(at => 
                    at.Id.ToString().Contains(searchString)
                ||
                    at.Name.Contains(searchString));
         break;
    }
}
```

I want return all query which have the same enums

Comment: Please turn this into runnable code. The code doesn't compile:  `inlude x` and `a.Color` are invalid.

Comment: Sorry but this was example beacue I have no idea how do this such method ling :(

Comment: I don't understand how the text in your question relates to the code. Can you clarify?

Comment: You're asking a lot of similar questions at the moment. It sounds like you're struggling with the idea of enums, searching for text, and linq. It's hard to tell what is really the issue you're facing. Can you talk in more general terms about what you're trying to do?

Comment: I have other question => if (Enum.TryParse<Color>(searchString, out tryParseResult))
{
    Console.WriteLine("YES");

}
else
{

Console.WriteLine("No");
}
I don't need " out tryParseResul   " there is another method Enum.TryParse<Color> bit without "out"

Comment: @KrzysztofBojarczuk - Why are you trying to write code like this? Please describe your problem in more general terms.

Comment: @KrzysztofBojarczuk - And just write an extension method to remove the `out`.

Comment: beacuse I am sending request to front-edn app. and I have reguestQuery = requestGuery.Where(x => enumColor.Contains(x.Color.ToString()) and eveyrthing works but i don't  need now out tryParseResult

Comment: @KrzysztofBojarczuk - Can you describe ***in more general terms*** what you are trying to do? Something like, I have a website where users enter colours of the cars they would like to purchase and I have to see what cars are in stock that match those colours.

Comment: Thanks for help I asked people on discord and they anwsered on my guestion

Comment: @KrzysztofBojarczuk - It seems like you are having some issues understanding. I'd like to help if I still can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return all cars, then you need to change the return type to `List` and then lets assume that you have some list of cars (`List<Car>`) and we should pick cars from there by name and color:

```
public async Task<List<Car>> GetAllCars(string searchString)
{
    return cars.Where(x=>x.Name.Contains(searchString) || x.Color.ToString().Contains(searchString).ToList();
}
```